# Using strings from user in exec function

Tags: c, exec

I want to use `exec()` with a word the user sends, currently I tried and resulted in a "invalid argument" error, is my idea doable, and if yes how?

Current code:

```
char word[30];
recv(new_sock, &word, sizeof(word), 0);
char command[1024];
sprintf(command,"%s %s","grep -w -i",word);
char *exp[] = {command, NULL};
execvp(exp[0], exp);
```

Comment: Note that `recv` does not null-terminate the string. So unless the null is sent from the sender, you need to add it.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I fixed this by doing the following: `int n=recv(..); word[n]='\0';` but that didn't fix the error

Comment: I don't really use `execvp` but I think it should be `char *exp[] = {"grep", "-w", "-i", word, NULL}; execvp(exp[0], exp);`

Comment: thank you, this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had 2 issues. First, `recv` does not null-terminate the string. So unless the null is sent from the sender, you need to add it. Second, the parameters to `execvp` were not correct:

```
int bytes_rcvd;
char word[30];
if ((bytes_rcvd = recv(new_sock, &word, sizeof(word), 0)) > 0 && bytes_rcvd < sizeof(word)) {
    word[bytes_rcvd] = '\0';
    const char *exp[] = {"grep", "-w", "-i", word, NULL};
    execvp(exp[0], exp);
}
```